# Vertx Streaming zip file to http response

Tags: java, vert.x

Im trying to stream a zip file as output  for the user to download. I create a zipOutputStream, and have tried to send it into the vertx http response.

However this download a corrupt zip file or hangs

```
 public void download(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos)) {

      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        String fileName = "test" + i + ".csv";
        File tempFile = createTempFile("test" + i);
        tempFile.deleteOnExit();

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(buffer);

        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);

        try {
          zos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
          zos.closeEntry();

          String b64String = Base64.encodeBase64String(baos.toByteArray());

          routingContext.response()
            .setChunked(true)
            .putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/zip")
            .putHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test.zip\"")
            .putHeader(HttpHeaders.TRANSFER_ENCODING, "chunked")
            .putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, Long.toString(b64String.length()));

          routingContext.response().write(b64String);
          routingContext.response().end();
          routingContext.response().close();

        } finally {
          baos.close();
        }
      }

    }
    catch(Exception ex) {

    }

  }
```

Comment: why do you need a file for that? also, what's the point to use zipping, if you send it as Base64 (25% size increase)?

Comment: Could you please provide the Vert.x related code, how are you calling the mentioned `#download` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out the solution. I wrapped the vertx httpResponse in an outputStream, and pushed that into zipOutputStream. And it worked, by setting chunked to true.

Comment: Could you share the related code?

Comment: mind to share the code ? thanks

Comment: can you please share the code, how you wrapped

Answer (score 0):

For very big files, you can use streaming to avoid loading them completely into RAM:

```
AsyncInputStream fileContent = new AsyncInputStream(routingContext.vertx(), fileInputStream);
fileContent.endHandler((ev) -> {
    routingContext.response().end();        
});
Pump.pump(fileContent, routingContext.response()).start();
```

Unfortunately, AsyncInputStream (wrapper for InputStream into ReadStream) is not yet part of VertX framework so you have to implement it yourself or find some open source implementation.